# Checking for NULL in a SQL query

Tags: sql

[image: ER Diagram]

So here's my homework question: List all artists and the number of unique composers that they had, only for those artists who had greater than zero composers. Note that there are some composer values that have NULL values; do not count these! Your output columns should be listed as ArtistName and ComposerCount in that order.

Here's my answer thus far:

```
SELECT  Distinct Track.Composer AS ArtistName, Count(*) AS ComposerCount
FROM Artist,Album,Track 
WHERE Artist.ArtistID = Album.ArtistID AND Track.AlbumID = Album.AlbumId 
GROUP BY Track.Composer
HAVING Count(*) > 0
```

My Problem: I don't understand how to not count null values in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

check this.

```
   SELECT  Distinct Track.Composer AS ArtistName, Count(Composer ) AS ComposerCount
    FROM Artist,Album,Track 
    WHERE Artist.ArtistID = Album.ArtistID AND Track.AlbumID = Album.AlbumId 
    and Track.Composer is not null
    GROUP BY Track.Composer
    HAVING Count(Composer ) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

So not sure, but try the simple trick of using Not Null
for ex:

```
WHERE Artist.ArtistID = Album.ArtistID AND 
Track.AlbumID = Album.AlbumId AND
Artist.ArtistID is Not NULL
```